# How can I check disk usage using ssh?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, disk-usage, network-monitoring

We have an ssh server on Ubuntu and we want a disk usage report using ssh of whole network.Is there any utility, command, or script available to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you considered network monitor services like nagios, zabbix, cacti etc? http://alternativeto.net/software/nagios/?platform=linux&license=free -- On the other hand, you could set a cron script to email you the data per server (it's much safer, since it doesn't require password or key logins)

Answer (score 21):

You can use `df -h` to see the free space, used space, and total space of all partitions on the system.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting to see the disk usage on the SSH remotely? As in, "log in to SSH server and then show the disk usage"?

If so...

```
ssh user@host "df -h"
```

That's assuming you have key logins enabled so it doesn't prompt you for a password.

Answer (score 1):

ssh to your  host then:

to show all folder sizes for the current directory recursively, with their sizes:

```
du -h
```

If you run this from a high-level directory, it can take a while to complete.

Show a disk use summary for the current directory:

```
du -sh
```

Again, this can take a little while if you're running it in a high-level directory.